# Please help me convert SQL to LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have this query that i've been trying to figure out how to convert to LINQ:

```
select bjbecd, bjbesk, areotx 
from insku 
inner join iniwre on bjcomp=a7comp and bjbecd=a7becd and bjbesk=a7besk 
inner join initem on bjcomp=arcomp and bjbecd=arbecd 
where a7comp=1 and 
a7wcde in (1,10) and 
a7ohdq>0 and rtrim(a7becd) + rtrim(a7besk) not in
(select skucode from eoditems)
```

And here is my LINQ so far:

```
(from i in db.INSKUs
    join w in db.INIWREs on 
        new { i.BJCOMP, i.BJBECD, i.BJBESK }
        equals  
        new { w.A7COMP, w.A7BECD, w.A7BESK } 
    join t in db.INITEMs on 
        new { i.BJCOMP, i.BJBECD }
        equals 
        new { t.ARCOMP, t.ARBECD }
    where w.A7COMP == 1
    where w.A7WCDE == 1 || w.A7WCDE == 10
    where w.A7OHDQ > 0
    where !(from z in db.EODItems
            select z.SkuCode).Contains(w.A7BECD.TrimEnd() + w.A7BESK.TrimEnd())
    select new { i.BJBECD, i.BJBESK, t.AREOTX }
);
```

I am getting an error message on the first join stating"The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect. Type inference failed in the call to 'Join'."

All searches I did, related to type match errors, but I quadruple checked all my types within the joins, and they are the same.

Comment: Did you setup your foreign keys already? If so, this can be trivial.

Comment: Have you tried cutting out one of the joins (and everything that depends on it) to see if it would compile/run?  At least that way you could narrow it down to which one its' complaining about?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to do something like this :

```
join w in db.INIWREs on 
 new { i.BJCOMP, i.BJBECD, i.BJBESK }
    equals  
       new { BJCOMP = w.A7COMP, BJBECD = w.A7BECD, BJBESK  = w.A7BESK }
```

Should work.

Comment: This makes sense. The properties should be exactly the same.

Comment: Tigran, thank you for this, it worked, sorry for the late response.